# I need to set value of my ComboBox depending on selection of other ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I tried to change value of my combobox when previous combobox is selected, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

When forms load I fill first `ComboBox`:

```
List<Tax> listOfActiveTaxes = TaxesController.SelectAll();

int IndexOfTax = TaxesController.SelectAll().FindIndex(a => a.Value == DefaultTaxValue);

cmbTaxes.ItemsSource = listOfActiveTaxes;
cmbTaxes.DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
cmbTaxes.SelectedValue = "Id";
cmbTaxes.SelectedIndex = IndexOfTax;
```

And I need to change value of this `cmbTaxes` if Cmb above is selected (CmbGroups), so when cmb above is selected I did next:

```
private void cmbGroups_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

  var selectedGroup = (Group)cmbGroups.SelectedItem;
  if (selectedGroup != null && selectedGroup.Id > 0)
  {

   //Not changing when I select any Group
   cmbTaxes.SelectedItem = selectedGroup.Tax;
  }

}
```

Comment: `cmbTaxes.SelectedValue = "Id";` Is `Id` the name of a property, or the value of a property? If it's the *name* of a property, what you want is `cmbTaxes.SelectedValuePath = "Id";` Also, please consider dymanoid's suggestion to do this in XAML with bindings. It'll be very simple and straightforward that way.

Comment: Not really important question, but anyway: why are you not using any `Binding`s but rather directly setting the properties in code-behind? We're in a WPF world...

Comment: @mm8 List<Tax> listOfActiveTaxes = TaxesController.SelectAll();

Comment: @EdPlunkett cmbGroups.SelectedItem has Tax object inside, and I want to : depending on which group is selected
to set my cmbTaxes depending on Group's Tax (because there is Tax object inside allready).

Comment: @Roxy'Pro If you don't want to answer a question, just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `SelectedValuePath` property of `cmbTaxes` to "Id":

```
cmbTaxes.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
```

...and set the `SelectedValue` property of it to the `Id` of the `Tax`:

```
private void cmbGroups_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedGroup = (Group)cmbGroups.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedGroup != null && selectedGroup.Id > 0)
    {
        cmbTaxes.SelectedValue = selectedGroup.Tax.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why is that?

Comment: This is how SelectedValue works. You set it to a value that matches the value of the property specified by the SelectedValuePath property of the item to be selected.

Comment: I thought I need to use SelectedItem there, because I thought it's all about SelectedItem ..